# Reusable command-console widget library or app

Tags: command-line

I'm developing a Windows-based, C++ app, for which I want to add a command console. The app is a toy 3d editor.

I have a basic console running using ImGui, but it's got some issues that are difficult to overcome because of some ImGui limitations. For example, copying and pasting text entered into the console.

What I would like would be something like this:

A C/C++ library that can be added to a Windows C++ app, which creates a console-like widget. Note that this would not be a library to manipulate the builtin windows ConEmu; instead, the library creates its own Win32 widget and handles the console-like functionality.
If #1 is not available, then a stand-along app, with which I could communicate via some type of RPC mechanism, such as Native Windows Events, or the like.

I either case, the idea is to be able to send and receive messages to this console lib/app, for things like printing text, receiving text input, copy/paste, setting color output, etc.

The point is to add command console functionality to my toy 3d editor, using an actual Windows widget, instead of the ImGui library.

I've been looking for something like this, but haven't found something usable, yet.